# Two Options for Outlet in Bathroom Bidet

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, code-compliance

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of adding a bidet outlet to our master bathroom. Our house was built around 2018/2019 and as such has all of the master bathroom outlets on its own 20amp circuit. I can tap into the circuit in the attic which is past the GCFI and drop a line down to the room with the toilet. There is another option which is tap into the light switch box which is powering the lights in the room albeit this is only a 15amp circuit and probably powering a few other rooms as well.

The thing I need help with is advice if there are any positives/negatives I'm not aware of, and if I'm violating code by tapping into the 20amp bathroom countertop outlet circuit. I know that the 20amp circuit must be for only the bathroom, but I'm not sure how code defines the "room" here e.g. is the room with the toilet a totally different room and would be against code.

The bidet runs about 500 watts max which leaves enough room for most accessories on the countertop circuit, except for the hungriest of hair dryers. I'd prefer to not have my lights dim when the bidet kicks on heat mode.

Here's a picture for reference. I'm standing in the master bathroom, looking at the toilet room which has a door (idk if that is relevant).

[image: Layout]

I live in WA state but I doubt that is relevant here. I'm also asking since a lot of the time, people are just saying "as long as its behind a GCFI its fine" which I don't think is always true with updated codes.

Comment: If the 20A circuit supplies only that bathroom, you are permitted to have additional, non-countertop outlets in the bathroom. Or tap into another circuit as you see fit. By code (Bathroom definition in Article 100), a bathroom is defined as "An area including a sing (basin) with one or more of the following: a toilet, ... a bidet, ...") - the fact there is a door will likely be interpreted as for privacy, not to make the toilet a separate room from the bathroom.

Comment: You would need to check if the light circuit has GFCI protection or use a GFCI receptacle, if you use the light circuit.

Comment: My personal preference is to have a GFCI receptacle so it trips (hopefully) before any GFCI breaker trips and takes out the light as well, leaving you in the dark at an awkward time.

Comment: Why would you go into the attic to find a tap-in point? From your photo, you can simply pull the yellow 12/2 cable from the counter outlet box,  drop it down to a box near the toilet, and then run another length of 12/2 back to the counter box.

Comment: @Jon that doesn't work. GFCIs aren't breakers with varying thresholds.  Since current is equal everywhere in a series loop, every GFCI sees the exact same ground fault simultaneously. Detection is much faster than interruption, so all will detect and place their trip hammers in motion before any move enough to actually interrupt.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - in theory yes. In practice I see the closest one trip, not the further ones. Likely line impedance helping out.

Comment: @Kreemoweet everything is stapled behind drywall and I'd be unlikely get enough slack on a wire to be able to pull it into a junction box.

Comment: Thanks all for the insight, its much appreciated.

Comment: @Jon Line impedance doesn't effect current, so "be careful with your sample size here".

Answer (score 6):

As of NEC 2020, bathroom receptacles *which do not* serve countertops are allowed to be on any circuit.   A bidet socket is an example. Feel free to tap any circuit that is convenient e.g. a bedroom circuit or lights.

If lights dim when loads come on, that sounds like very cheap LEDs that are ultra sensitive to voltage because they use a cheap capacitive dropper.  Those don't last anyway.  Better LEDs use a switching power supply that ignores voltage variations.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the non countertop receptacle part of the code. I may poke around the attic to see what else is available on a 20amp circuit. Maybe bedroom outlets or something like that.